# Swiftui - only show a percentage of a view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a `RoundedRectangle`, and my objective is to lay another `RoundedRectangle` over it such that the overlay shows a "percentage complete". I can't seem to find the proper incantation to do so, though.

I *think* that ideally, the overlay should somehow only show a percentage of itself. Resizing itself to match the percentage skews the shape of the overlay.

```
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var value: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geom in
            VStack {
                Slider(value: self.$value, in: 0...1, step: 0.01)

                ZStack {
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        // The main rectangle
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(Color.blue)
                            .frame(width: geom.size.width,
                                   height: 200)

                        // The progress indicator...
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .fill(Color.red)
                            .opacity(0.5)
                            .frame(width: CGFloat(self.value) * geom.size.width,
                                   height: 200)
                    }

                    Text("\(Int(self.value * 100)) %")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

In the above playground, if you look at 1, 2, or even 3 %, you can see that the red overlay is out of the blue background rectangle bounds in the upper and lower left. See image below.

[image: Red overlay out of bounds...]

I feel like this is not the proper solution, but I also couldn't find the right mix of things (trying `scaleEffect`, a bunch of `offset` and `position` math) to really nail it.

To me, like I said above, it feels like the overlay should be able to say "only make my left-most 40% visible" when the value is `0.4`.

That was long-winded, I apologize for that. If you've read this far, and have any advice to impart, I'd be incredibly appreciative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how I approach it so I don't have to manage more than one `cornerRadius`.

```
VStack {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

        // The main rectangle
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: geom.size.width,
                   height: 200)

        // The progress indicator...
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .opacity(0.5)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(self.value) * geom.size.width,
                   height: 200)
    }
    .cornerRadius(10)
```

Comment: You could then directly use the color instead of a Rectangle?

Answer (score 4):

If I correctly understood your concern, here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

[image: demo]

```
ZStack {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {

        // The main rectangle
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: geom.size.width,
                   height: 200)

        // The progress indicator...
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(Color.red)
            .opacity(0.5)
            .frame(width: CGFloat(self.value) * geom.size.width,
                   height: 200)
    }
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))    // << here !!
```